# Why are some images in Windows 10 Mail disproportionately large?

Tags: email, html, windows-10-mail-app

This is an unusual issue with Windows 10's Mail app which can probably be chalked up to a bug, but I'd like to make sure I don't have some weird setting enabled first.

In *some* emails I receive, *some* of the images are larger than warranted, which usually throws the whole presentation into a jumble, introduces otherwise unnecessary scrollbars, etc. It's clearly not how the author intended it to look, as it looks normal in other email clients and web interfaces I use. Attached are two images to illustrate the problem.

The first is the correct view, as seen in Chrome 63. This is what I see if I open the email in any other client other than Windows 10 Mail. The second is what I see in Windows 10 Mail. Notice that the logo banner is disproportionately large compared to the surrounding text and the NFL logo immediately below it.

Has anyone else seen this? Do I have a weird setting enabled or is this a known bug?

[image: The email's "Web Version" in Chrome 63, as it ought to look.]
[image: The email in Windows 10 Mail, with a disproportionate "twitch" logo]

Comment: "Coding email is hard

You've tried to code an email template before and run into trouble.

There are over 30 major email clients using different rendering engines and various email providers like Outlook, Gmail, Apple, Yahoo Mail. Email requires special development skills."

Comment: Note to readers: the SU site renders the two images at different sizes.  To view what the question refers to, click open the two images at full size.  The problem is that the "twitch" box is rendered at a larger size in the second image.  The other page elements appear to be the same, although wrapping of the text at the bottom is affected by the available width due to the size of the twitch element.